# Сбор данных из разных файлов в одну таблицу Excel(VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, макросы

Я новичок в освоении макросов для Excel, но передо мной была поставлена задача, сделать сбор некоторой информации в автоматическом или полуавтоматическом режиме.

Итак дано:

- 1-я таблица (main.xlsm) - в нее должны собираться все данные.
- 2-я, 3-я, 4-я, n-я... таблицы откуда берутся данные.

Все таблицы названы однотипно - 1_novgorod.xls, 2_dmitrov.xls, 3_shachty.xls и т.д. Во всех файлах внутри одинаковые таблицы, с двумя полями:

| Наименование | - | Количество |

| Продукт            | - | 1500            |

| Продукт 2         | - | 1700            |

Каждый новый день, города шлют нам эти же файлы, с новыми данными, за текущие сутки. Может кто помочь, написать или ткнуть на похожий пример, где данные необходимо писать на отдельный лист в книгу за текущие сутки, а при появлении новых данных на след. день, то их копировать уже на новый лист с датой в названии листа (например так: 28.04.18 или просто 28.04).

На данный момент, мой код(солянка) позволяет выбрать файл для копирования из него данных, но они (данные) вставляются в прописанную вручную ячейку (например С3). Если например, повторно запустить макрос и взять уже другой файл, то данные перезапишутся в этой же ячейке (С3), хотя необходимо, чтобы они записались в ячейке, для соответствующего города. И так пока все города (их 15) не пришлют за текущий день данные.

```
Sub macr3()
 Dim sFolder As String, sFiles As String

 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
 If .Show = False Then Exit Sub
  sFiles = .SelectedItems(1)
 End With

 sFolder = sFolder & IIf(Right(sFolder, 1) = Application.PathSeparator, "", 
 Application.PathSeparator)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 sFolder = Dir(sFiles & "*.xls*")
 If sFiles <> "" Then

Workbooks.Open sFiles & sFolder

 'копируем нужный диапазон в откр. книге
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Лист1").Range("B2:B16").Copy

 'закрываем книгу которую открывали для копирования
 ActiveWorkbook.Close

 'активируем нужную книгу
 Workbooks("main.xlsm").Activate

 'выделяем и вставляем скопированные данные
 ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("04_06").Range("C3").Select
 ActiveSheet.Paste

 End If

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Буду рад, любой помощи.

Comment: А чем не устроила штатная консолидация данных (лента "Данные", блок "Работа с данными")?

Comment: @Akina сложно сказать, я Excel очень редко касался и честно сказать по-старой памяти, сразу предположил, что лучше сразу в макросы углубиться. Спасибо за наводку, изучу как разберусь уже с тем, что начал делать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создается новый лист, в столбцы *A:C* копируются данные всех файлов из указанной папки

```
Sub CopyData()
Dim aTemp()
Dim wBook As Workbook, sht As Worksheet
Dim sPath As String, sFName As String, sSity As String
Dim lRw As Long, lRwStart As Long, i As Long
    If MsgBox("Обработать файлы?", 64 + vbYesNo, "ОБРАБОТКА") = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "проверить\" ' путь к папке с файлами
    If Dir(sPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MsgBox "В папке с файлом-обработчиком" & _
                    Chr$(10) & "Не найдена папка ""проверить""", 64, "ОШИБКА": Exit Sub

    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
    Set sht = Worksheets.Add

    With sht
        .Name = Format(Date, "dd_mm")
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Наименование":
        .Cells(1, 2).Value = "Кол-во"
        .Cells(1, 3).Value = "Город"
    End With

    lRwStart = 2
    sFName = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*", vbReadOnly)

    Do While sFName <> ""
        Set wBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath & sFName)  ' открыть книгу

        With wBook
            With .Worksheets(1)
                lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

                If lRw > 1 Then
                    aTemp = .Range("A2:C" & lRw).Value
                    sSity = Split(sFName, ".")(0)

                    For i = 1 To lRw - 1: aTemp(i, 3) = sSity: Next i
                    sht.Cells(lRwStart, 1).Resize(lRw - 1, 3).Value = aTemp
                    lRwStart = lRwStart + lRw
                End If
            End With

            .Close
        End With

        sFName = Dir ' следующий файл
    Loop

    Set wBook = Nothing: Set sht = Nothing
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
    MsgBox "OK", 64, ""
End Sub
```

Надо бы добавить проверку наличия листа с указанным именем...

' -----------------------------------

Если даннные копировать последовательно не по строкам, а по столбцам.

Меняем переменную:

*lRwStart As Long* на *lClmn As Long*

Изменяем два фрагмента макроса:

```
'-------------------'
With sht
    .name = Format(Date, "dd_mm")
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Наименование"
End With

lClmn = 2
sFName = Dir(sPath & "*.xls*", vbReadOnly)
'-------------------'
        With .Worksheets(1)
            lRw = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

            If lRw > 1 Then
                If lClmn = 2 Then
                    aTemp = .Range("A2:B" & lRw).Value
                    sht.Cells(2, 1).Resize(lRw - 1, 2).Value = aTemp
                Else
                    aTemp = .Range("B2:B" & lRw).Value
                    sht.Cells(2, lClmn).Resize(lRw - 1, 1).Value = aTemp
                End If

                sht.Cells(1, lClmn).Value = Split(sFName, ".")(0)
                lClmn = lClmn + 1
            End If
        End With
'-------------------'
```

Наименования во всех файлах должны быть расположены одинаково.

Comment: Спасибо за приведенный пример, но в одной строке возникает ошибка. `object doesn't support this property or method`   <br>  ругается на эту запись:  *lRw = .UserdRange.Rows.Count*

Comment: Буква лишняя: *.UserdRange= .UsedRange*. Писал с клавы, без проверки...  Если еще будут ошибки - лучше перейти в чат.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, это почти то, что нужно. Только скрипт, копирует и названия из поля **А** _| продукт |_, и значения из поля **В**. В первой итерации скопировалась полностью таблица из первого файла, а во второй, скопировалось тоже все, но значения подставились снизу первой таблицы, а хотелось бы, чтобы они вставали рядом(справа) от первой и только значения, т.к. названия строк уже заданы

Comment: https://ibb.co/egKR9H ссылка на примерный вид таблицы

Comment: Добавил в ответ